# Strust2 tiles definition issue with "controllerClass" attribute

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, tiles, tiles-3

I am just rewriting an old project in a newer one and while copying tiles-definition files I was getting an issue on "controllerClass" attribute which is pointing towards a java class which is the controller class for a particular jsp

This is the exact issue
"Attribute "controllerClass" must be declared for element type "definition"."

in struts-tiles where all the attribute are defined there is 
in definition tag

```
<attribute>
    <name>controllerClass</name>
    <required>false</required>
    <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
</attribute>
```